# Precision: (1-1e-17)==1

Tags: r, floating-point, precision, floating-point-precision

What's the precision of R? Can I change it? I find that `(1-1e-16)==1` is FALSE, but `(1-1e-17)==1` is TRUE.

I tried to calculate

```
x = 1e-17
q1 = qnorm(x)
q2 = qnorm(1-x)
```

Theoretically `q1==-q2`, but the output of R is

```
>  x=1e-17
>  qnorm(x)
[1] -8.493793
>  qnorm(1-x)
[1] Inf
```

Any way to avoid such difference?

Answer (score 4):

Floating point precision depends on your system. You can get the relevant information from `help(".Machine")`.

E.g., `double.eps` is "the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1".

```
.Machine$double.eps
#[1] 2.220446e-16
```

And `double.neg.eps` is "a small positive floating-point number x such that 1 - x != 1".

```
.Machine$double.neg.eps
#[1] 1.110223e-16
```

Comment: Any way to change that?

Comment: No, it's a property of your system. There are of course ways to deal with or work around floating point precision issues, but you need to ask a more specific question if you need help with that.

Comment: E.g., `qnorm` has the `log.p` parameter.

Comment: Yes I checked that double.eps is 2.220446e-16. But any precision issue about smallest positive(negative) floating-point number x such that x!=0?

Comment: Are there any common systems where R uses something other than IEEE 754 binary64 format?

Comment: You can't change precision in base R, but there are ways to do high-precision arithmetic; they will all cost you in terms of computation time and generality ... http://rwiki.sciviews.org/doku.php?id=misc:r_accuracy:high_precision_arithmetic

Comment: No, `double.eps` is **not** “the smallest positive floating-point number x such that 1 + x != 1”. It is the difference between the successor of 1.0 and 1.0. See http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2013/05/09/FLT_EPSILON